# How to Make These Functions Run in Order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following functions. The problem I'm having is that the `updateInterviewArrays()` has a loop in it to fetch and store data, which works. But I need the `updateStates` and `doScoreMath` functions called after it to wait, and go in order after it's finished.  I can't seem to make that happen though.

```
componentDidMount() {

        this.getScoresFromTables();

    }


getScoresFromTables() {
        fetch(API_URL + `/interviews/${this.props.auditId}`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({completedInterviews: result}, () => this.updateInterviewArrays());
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(this.updateStates())
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(this.doScoreMath());
  }


    updateInterviewArrays() {
        const totalInterviews = this.state.completedInterviews.length;

        const tableSections = [
            'audit_general',
            'audit_culture',
            'audit_performance',
            'audit_policies',
            'audit_risk',
            'audit_strategy',
            'audit_rewards',
            'audit_workforce'
        ];

        for (let i = 0; i < totalInterviews; i++){
            for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                
                this.grabTableData(tableSections[i], this.state.completedInterviews[j].employee_id);
            }
        }
    }


async grabTableData (tableName, employeeId) {
        await fetch(API_URL + `/responses/${tableName}/${employeeId}`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((result) => {
                if (tableName === "audit_general") {
                    tableData.audit_general.push(result[0]);
                } else if (tableName === "audit_culture") {
                    tableData.audit_culture.push(result[0]);
                } else if (tableName === "audit_performance") {
                    tableData.audit_performance.push(result[0]);
                } else if (tableName === "audit_policies") {
                    tableData.audit_policies.push(result[0]);
                } else if (tableName === "audit_risk") {
                    tableData.audit_risk.push(result[0]);
                } else if (tableName === "audit_strategy") {
                    tableData.audit_strategy.push(result[0])
                } else if (tableName === "audit_rewards") {
                    tableData.audit_rewards.push(result[0]);
                } else if (tableName === "audit_workforce") {
                    tableData.audit_workforce.push(result[0]);
                }
                console.log(result);
                console.log(tableData);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            // .then(() => this.updateStates())
            // .catch((error) => {
            //     console.log(error);
            // })
            // .then(() => this.doScoreMath())
            ;
    }
```

Comment: And from where are you calling `getScoresFromTables()`? Post the whole component(if it is large, then delete some unnecessary parts) so that we can suggest you modify your existing component. Without looking at the component and how functions are being called, you might get suggestions that are not feasible for you. So, try to post a short and concise reproducible component so you can get suggestions feasible for your use-case.

Comment: I just added it, I actually just call `getScoresFromTables()` from `componentDidMount()`, it's the first thing that happened.  But I also added my `grabTableData()`, because you can see that I have calls to `updateStates()` and `doScoreMath()` commented out,  which worked fine from there.  But they get called with each loop.  So I wast trying to move them to the `getScoresFromTables()` so that they only get called once at the end.  That's when I realize in that case, they do not wait until `updateIntervewArrays()` is done.

Comment: have whatever functions that supposed to wait do some fast intervals, something like 1ms.. and then in the updateinteriew arrays thingy.. when it's finished make some global varialbe 1 or something.. inside the waiting functions, it will run `if(globalVar==1){do what im supposed to}`